# Bed wobbling on Ender 3

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling, bed

I have an Ender 3 3d printer. It has a bed that wobbles because it came with only 1 bed support beam.

[image: Ender 3 bed plate support]

Every model I print, I must print vertically, because the closer it gets to the edges of the build plate, the less adhesion it has.

Is there anything I can to to fix this problem?

Comment: It the bed actually wobbling or is it just not flat or not level. If it's wobbling the cause is not the single beam but something loose, probably the eccentric nuts on the Y axis rollers.

Comment: The bed is level, the problem is that the wheels on the rail are a bit too far apart. How do i fix this?

Comment: Two of the wheels have an adjustable eccentric nut between the bed carriage and the wheels. They are hexagonal, so you can use the spanner included with the printer to turn them - tighten them just enough to stop the wobble; none of the wheels should be able to turn freely without moving the bed. You may need to re-level the bed afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the V roller wheels aren't tight on the Y axis beam, it means the eccentric nuts are not adjusted correctly. Two of the rollers are mounted centered on the holes in the carriage frame, but the other two are on eccentric nuts which displace them from center slightly depending on the orientation the nut is turned to, to allow tightening and loosening of the grip on the beam. Since the Y axis ones are hard to see under the bed, look at the X or Z ones to get an idea what to expect.

Note that the bolt through the whole roller assembly can loosen when adjusting the eccentric nut. You can probably avoid this by figuring out the right direction to turn it and only going that direction (continuing around just under 360 degrees if you go too far). If you do loosen the bolt then the eccentric nut will move on its own under vibration, so you need to re-tighten it. For the Y axis this might require taking off the bed or taking the carriage off the beam (by removing the belt and tensioner).